# Inverse Django lookup filtering

Tags: django, django-models

So I have two models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    course_member = models.ForeignKey(CourseMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE

class CourseMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

How can I get all the CourseMembers that have 2 or more members?

And, how do I stop CourseMember from having more than 1 Member.

I was thinking about using Aggregate and Group by, but I wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: No more than one would be a `OneToOne` relationship with `null=True` if zero is OK, not a `ForeignKey`. Guessing the other would be to annotate with a CourseMember query with the count of member_set, and then filter on the annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get all the CourseMembers that have 2 or more members?

You can use annotate for this and to do this it'll be easier if you add related_name to course_member field of Member for example: `course_member = models.ForeignKey(CourseMember, related_name='coursemember_member', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` using this related_name you can do reverse lookup to refer child table from parent table and annotate like this: `CourseMember.objects.annotate(Count('coursemember_member')).filter(coursemember_member__count__gt=1)` this will give your desired result.

> And, how do I stop CourseMember from having more than 1 Member.

This can be achieved at ORM/Database level or at program level, to achieve this at ORM level you can make course_member One-to-one relation instead of many-to-one relation like this `course_member = models.OneToOneField(CourseMember, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` here database throws exception if you try to insert multiple rows with same course_member or else at program level you can achieve it by checking if a row exists with the same course_member if it exists handle it.

Comment: Quick question, How would I be able to do this using Member instead of CourseMember? So I don't do a reverse lookup.

Comment: Then you have to make two queries one to get course_member ids from Member model and one to get CourseMember data using course_member ids like this " course_member_ids = Member.objects.values('course_member').annotate(Count('id')).filter(id__count__gt=1).values_list('course_member', flat=True) " from this you can get course_member ids and using these ids you can get course_member like this CourseMember.objects.filter(id__in=course_member_ids)